# Using SVG <image> as cover inside proportion less SVG

Tags: css, svg

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/7dtxgfd5/2/)**

**Objective:** I am trying to create a triangle shaped proportion less image in HTML.

**My Approach:** I have decided to use SVG to achieve this by creating a polygon triangle that can stretch & shrink to fit any dimension and used it as a mask on image that is suppose to fit in any dimension without loosing its own proportion.

**Issue:** Although the shape is working as I want but the background image stretches with the shape, is there any way I can make the image behave to something similar like css `background-size: cover` property.

**Code:**

HTML

```
<div id="svg-container">
    <svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" style='background-color: whitesmoke'>
        <defs>
          <polygon id="mask" points="0,0 0,100 0,100 100,0" />
          <pattern id="image" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0">
              <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"/>
          </pattern>
      </defs>
      <use xlink:href="#mask" fill="url(#image)"></use>
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#svg-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

To check same issue using SVG `image` tag [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/WpeH4/482/).

Comment: Could this be the issue `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

Comment: @Paulie_D I need to keep the shape proportion-less, If I remove that property the shape constrains to a 1:1 ratio.

Comment: So you don't want the shape to preserve it's aspect ratio but have a problem with the image stretching...**that's no logical.**

Comment: @Paulie_D :) I get your point but different parent ratio works all the time in css i.e that position absolute + negative translate technique (is there something similar we can do here?) and + I used `clip-path` with this same polygon and it worked fine but browser compatibility issues.